# jQuery UI resizable: ghost option not working correctly

Tags: jquery-ui

I've got the following:

```
<div class="tile ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resize me</h3>
    You should see a ghost outline.
</div>
```

and:

```
$('.tile').resizable({
    ghost:true
});
```

And it resizes, but I don't see a semi-transparent part of the element.
I'm copying from [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#visual-feedback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I can see is that you are accessing the element from its class name rather than id. Have you tried using and id instead?

Edit: Just want to make sure you've also added css for the hover?

```
.ui-resizable-ghost { border: 1px dotted gray; }
```